# Can variables in Azure Pipelines be used in NodeJS code?

Tags: node.js, docker, variables, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Can variables in Azure Pipelines (Build/Release) be used in NodeJS code?

If not, can variables set in WebApp be used in NodeJS code as well?

I set variable TESTING & TESTING2 in both Pipelines' Builds and Release and below environment setting in .yaml file:

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: devops
      env:
      - name: TESTING
        value: $(TESTING)
```

Then just tried to print in NodeJS:

> process.env.TESTING --> $(TESTING)
>
> process.env.TESTING2 --> undefined

This is not work for me.

Comment: you can set the environment variables by going to the App settings and then add all the variable key and values.
you can access them in node using process.env['variable-key']

Comment: You should set both in docker. ARG in build phase, ENV in run phase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use Azure Pipelines variables like every environment variables in NodeJS:

```
var buildID = process.env.BUILD_BUILDID
```

Comment: I set variable TESTING & TESTING2 in both Pipelines' Builds and Release and below environment setting in .yaml file:
spec:
  containers:
  - name: devops
      env:
      - name: TESTING
        value: $(TESTING)

Then just tried to print in NodeJS:
process.env.TESTING --> $(TESTING)
process.env.TESTING2 --> undefined

This is not work for me.

Comment: @DaiKeung Did you find the solution? I am having the same issue.

Comment: Yes, you can get Azure Pipelines variables in .yaml file.

 spec:
   containers:
   - name: devops
  image: ACR_NAME.azurecr.io/devops:latest
  env:
  - name: AZURE_CLIENT_ID
    value: AzureClientId